# Xcode how to Autoshrink a UITextView?

Tags: xcode, text, textview, uitextview

I have a Text View box and I want that rectangle to stay the same size while the text inside autoshrinks to fit the box. The reason I need this is because the text is pulled from a plist and the strings are all different lengths. Labels have an Autoshrink feature which is exactly what I want, but I can't figure out a way even through code to get a Text View to do the same thing. Please help!

Comment: Why do you need `UITextView`? Why can't you use `UILabel`?

Comment: UILabels are only one line, centered in the middle. When I loaded the text from the NSDictionary it shrinks the text to tiny font and then adds a "..." at the end but the text is still only one line. I want the text to fill the entire box (about the whole size of the screen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UILabel`s can have more than one line of text.  You just need to set the following:

```
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.numberOfLines = 0; // 0 = unlimited number of lines, set to another number to have that as maximum
```

I'm not entirely sure if this works, but you can then combine this with `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;` to have a multi-line label that autoshrinks text.

Comment: This worked, thanks. A nice workaround but I wish I could do it in Text View.

Comment: The line breaks work but adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth doesn't work with multiple lined labels.